# TypeError, 'str' is not callable tkinter, random

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I want to make a random number generator, i made a GUI with **tkinter**, and I want to use the Entries to set `min. number` and `max. number` but I get this error:

> TypeError, 'str' is not callable it comes from  "i =
>   randint(str(min_val()), str(max_val()))"

here the full function:

```
def gen():
    min_val = str(entry1.get())
    max_val = str(entry2.get())

i = randint(str(min_val()), str(max_val()))
root.update_idletasks()
v.set(i)
```

Comment: randint function expects integer parameters. It seems that you pass string to randint function ( using function str())

Comment: What are you expecting `min_val()` to do that's different from `min_val`? Also, is this really how your code is written, with the last three lines _not_ indented to be inside of `gen()`?

Comment: Python will not throw an error that includes the phrase "it comes from ...". Can you please post the _exact_ error message, including the traceback?

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\python\Random Number Generator.py", line 18, in gen
    i = randint(str(min_val()), str(max_val()))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Answer (score -1):

You assigned the variable name `str` to a string somewhere. You shadowed the built-in `str` callable by doing so. Demo:

```
>>> str = 'hi'
>>> str(5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Solution: use a better variable name.

Comment: What's the downvote for? This *has* to be the reason why OP is getting a `TypeError`.